# Paginating firestore data with realtime additions on top of the result

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to load my data into chunks of 10 in react. I am listening for document addition using onSnapshot() firestore method. I want to paginate data and at the same time allow the recent addition to come to the top. How to apply this in the code below -

```
db.collection('palettes').orderBy("createdAt").onSnapshot(snapshot => { 
    snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {

          if (change.type === "added") {
               setPalette( prevPalette => ([
                   { id: change.doc.id, ...change.doc.data() },
                     ...prevPalette
                    ]))
                    setIsLoading(false)
                }
            })
     })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should save state of last document for pagination and realtime updates

**Example**

```js
const getPalettes = (pageSize, lastDocument) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let query = db.collection('palettes')
    .orderBy("createdAt")

  if(lastDocument) {
    query = query.startAt(lastDocument)
  }

  query = query.limit(pageSize);

  return query.onSnapshot(query => {
    const docs = query.docs.map(pr => ({pr.id, ...pr.data()}))
    resolve(docs);
  });
})

let unsubscribe = getPalettes(10).then(newPalettes => {
  setPalette(palettes => [...palettes, newPalettes]);
  lastPalette = newPalettes[newPalettes.length -1];
  setLastPalette(lastPalette);
  unsubscribe();
})

unsubscribe = getPalettes(10, lastPalette).then(newPalettes => {
  setPalette(palettes => [...palettes, newPalettes]);
  lastPalette = newPalettes[newPalettes.length -1];
  setLastPalette(lastPalette);
  unsubscribe();
})


const listenForLatestPalettes = (lastDocument, callback) => {
  return db.collection('palettes')
    .orderBy("createdAt")
    .startAt(lastDocument)
    .onSnapshot(callback);
}

const callback = snapshot => {
  for(let change of snapshot.docChanges()) {
    if (change.type === "added") {
      setPalette(palettes => {
        const palette = { id: change.doc.id, ...change.doc.data() };
        return [...palettes.filter(pal => pal.id !== id], palette];
      })
    }
  }
}

unsubscribe = listenForLatestPalettes(lastDocument, callback);
```