# Firestore: pagination without charging twice

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

I want to add some pagination (with listeners) to my collection but for that I need to first get the next n items and them create new listener from the first doc to the last doc.
this operation will make me charged twice - for the get and then, for the unnecessary first listener result.
can we avoid this situation?

Comment: Pagination and listeners simply do not work well with each other in Firestore.  There is no easy workaround.  Do a web search for "firestore pagination with listeners" to see what people have said and done about it. You will find a lot here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Firestore doesn't support pagination with listeners however, as stated by @Doug Stevenson, there are some workarounds that you can do about it that are already here in the community.

You may look at these threads for reference:

- [Paginating firestore data with realtime additions on top of the
  result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62308848/16895640)
- [How do I only get new documents from firebase using .onSnapshot when used with .limitToLast for pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63452890/16895640)
- [How paging work with realtime firestore query?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73338158/16895640)